# Checkbox look like radio buttons on iPad/iPad Mini?

Tags: css, ipad

Not sure why this is happening, but couldn't find anything on this. Every *input type="checkbox"* look like radio buttons on iPads. Has anyone come across this issue and if so, how were you able to fix the problem?

Thank you guys!

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkNow">Check Now
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot?

Comment: They look fine in the iOS simulator

Answer (score 2):

For Safari version 6, default checkbox styling has border-radius set to valid value. Clearing the border-radius value fixed the issue

```
input[type="checkbox"]{
   border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but mine was user-created.

I had a `width: auto;` on all my `input[type="radio"]`. Simply removing that, and not explicitly defining a width, fixed the issue.